# For a joint distribution with density$f(X,Y)$, does $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ implies $X$ and $Y$ being independent in genral?

Tags: probability-theory

For a normally distributed random vector $(X,Y)$, $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ implies $X$ and $Y$ being independent.

But how about other distribution?

Then for a $n\times n$ normally distributed random vector, if the the covariance matrix is a diagonal matrix, I guessed components of the random vectors are all independent of each other, is this correct?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I agree with your first statement, but I am not sure about the second statement because I encountered this question that has proved for $normally$ distributed random vector $(X,Y)$, $X,Y$ are independent if and only if $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$. So this make me wonder if there are other distribution that follow this in multivariate case

Comment: @RobertIsrael Partially, so why is multivariate normal so unique it has such property of $Cov(X,Y)$ implies independence between $X,Y$? is this due to its construction?

Comment: Very very easy to find examples where covariance is $0$ and the variables are not independent. Did you make any effort at all to find such an example?

Comment: @geetha290krm yes for univariate case, but I am not sure about multivariate case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Normal case yes, $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ implies $X , Y$ independent, if the covariance matrix is diagonal, we can say that they are independent.

In general $Cov(X,Y) = 0$  does not imply independence. See

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi} I(x^2 + y^2 \leq 1) $$

$Cov(X,Y) = 0$ but $f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) \neq f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Comment: Please read my comment above and this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1